# Android SQLite and huge data sets

Tags: java, android

We are creating an app for a client that has hundreds of megabytes of HTML in SQLite databases. We have implemented a way to query this data and scroll through it all in a reasonably fast manner. The issue is that some of the databases have very large queries (20,000+ rows) and we are seeing errors when we are growing the queries as the user is scrolling. So I guess the question is, what options do we have in querying and displaying tens of thousands of rows of data in Android?

Here is the stacktrace we're seeing:

```
09-10 19:19:12.575: WARN/IInputConnectionWrapper(640): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
09-10 19:19:18.226: DEBUG/dalvikvm(640): GC freed 446 objects / 16784 bytes in 330ms
09-10 19:19:32.886: ERROR/CursorWindow(19416): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 36, freeSpace() = 30, numRows = 17717
09-10 19:19:32.896: ERROR/CursorWindow(19416): not growing since there are already 17717 row(s), max size 1048576
09-10 19:19:32.916: ERROR/CursorWindow(19416): The row failed, so back out the new row accounting from allocRowSlot 17716
09-10 19:19:33.005: ERROR/Cursor(19416): Failed allocating fieldDir at startPos 0 row 17716
09-10 19:19:35.596: DEBUG/Cursor(19416): finish_program_and_get_row_count row 24315
09-10 19:19:41.545: DEBUG/dalvikvm(698): GC freed 2288 objects / 126080 bytes in 260ms
09-10 19:19:43.705: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(19416): No keyboard for id 0
09-10 19:19:43.717: WARN/KeyCharacterMap(19416): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
09-10 19:20:04.705: ERROR/CursorWindow(19416): need to grow: mSize = 1048576, size = 17, freeSpace() = 3, numRows = 17094
09-10 19:20:04.716: ERROR/CursorWindow(19416): not growing since there are already 17094 row(s), max size 1048576
09-10 19:20:04.726: ERROR/Cursor(19416): Failed allocating 17 bytes for text/blob at 17093,2
09-10 19:20:05.656: DEBUG/Cursor(19416): finish_program_and_get_row_count row 5257
09-10 19:24:54.685: DEBUG/dalvikvm(637): GC freed 9297 objects / 524176 bytes in 247ms
09-10 19:32:07.656: DEBUG/dalvikvm(19416): GC freed 9035 objects / 495840 bytes in 199ms
```

Here is our CursorAdapter code:

```
    private class MyAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super(context, R.layout.my_row, cursor);        
    }

    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {                
        RowData data = new RowData();
        data.setName(cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("name")));

        TextView tvItemText = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tvItemText);
        tvItemText.setText(data.getName());

        view.setTag(data);
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor runQueryOnBackgroundThread(CharSequence constraint) {
        /* Display the progress indicator */
        updateHandler.post(onFilterStart);

        /* Run the actual query */               
        if (constraint == null) {
            return myDbObject.getData(null);                     
        }

        return myDbObject.getData(constraint.toString());                
    }            
}
```

Comment: "what options do we have in querying and displaying tens of thousands of rows of data in Android?" --> eh? I can't even think why you might want to do that.

Comment: @SK9 This was for porting a medical reference app from iPhone to Android. They literally had tens of thousands of records in these SQLite databases. Any sane person would start entering a search term to narrow down the list but the iPhone app supported manually scrolling through all of the data perfectly fine too. Thus they expected the Android app to behave the same way.

Comment: I have a similar requirement.  One would be amazed at how many organizations use specialized apps in this manner.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

> what options do we have in querying
>   and displaying tens of thousands of
>   rows of data in Android?

You mean besides telling you that reading 20,000+ rows on a 3.5" LCD is bat-guano crazy? ;-)

It looks like `CursorWindow`, which is used somewhere under the covers, is having issues managing >17,000 rows. That could be one of two things:

1. You are out of heap space. With a 16MB non-compacting heap, and the fact that a `Cursor` holds the entire result set in the heap, that is not out of the question.
2. `CursorWindow` only supports 1MB of data, which is what the error message suggests more directly.

If there is a logical way to divide your queries into discrete chunks, you could do incremental queries and use `CursorJoiner` to stitch them together, and see if that helps.

But, in all seriousness, 20,000+ rows in a 3.5" screen, on a device that most closely resembles a 12-year-old PC in horsepower, is really asking a lot.

Comment: Unfortunately, it works like a charm on the iPhone and the client is expecting comparable performance. In this instance, it's just flat out breaking and that's all bad. We're breaking the query out to load a few rows at a time. The issue is when they "fling" to the bottom and expect to get to the bottom of the list.

Comment: *shrug* Find some way to keep your query results under 1MB. Request fewer columns. Pack your data better (e.g., don't use 8 INTEGER columns each for a boolean value -- use one INTEGER column and bitmasks). Come up with a UX that allows the user to consistently filter better, so you won't run into a 20K row result set. You can try to work around SQLiteCursor/SQLiteQuery using a CursorWindow, but I suspect your performance will be nasty.

Comment: I guess I wonder then what is the best way to scroll through a list smoothly when you have a table with 42,000 items and you're loading 30-40 at a time. It works for smaller tables but using LIMIT and OFFSET in the query for this particular database still causes ANR's and hiccups in the scrolling.

Comment: Have you thought about adjusting your UI MattC? For instance if, rather than a scrollbar, you could use up and down arrows to move the cursor position. This forces the user to make more device interaction, but makes them more forgiving of delay. It's not the best solution, but it would get rid of the unresponsiveness.

Comment: Another hack you could do: measure the rate of scrolling you can handle without uncomfortable pauses and artificially limit the users rate of scrolling to that.

Comment: It simple first get 100 rows using limit and when user scrolls down see at which number of row is currently and you can use re-query to load more data. If you are puting data in listview you can use managed cursor. Kindly see endless listview in android.

Answer (score 6):

If you really need that you can also split your data and read chunks like this:

```
   int limit = 0;
   while (limit + 100 < numberOfRows) {
       //Compose the statement
       String statement = "SELECT * FROM Table ORDER someField LIMIT '"+ limit+"', 100";
       //Execute the query
       Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(statement, null);
       while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
           Product product = new Product();
           product.setAllValuesFromCursor(cursor);
           productsArrayList.add(product);
      }
      cursor.close();
      limit += 100;
 }

 //Compose the statement
 String statement = "SELECT * FROM Table ORDER someField LIMIT '"+  (numberOfRows - limit)+"', 100";
 //Execute the query
 Cursor cursor = myDataBase.rawQuery(statement, null);

 while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
     Product product = new Product();
     product.setAllValuesFromCursor(cursor);
     productsArrayList.add(product);
 }
 cursor.close();
```

It's working under 2 s for 5k rows if you have indexed table.

Thanks,
Arkde

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, limiting queries makes it take a lot longer to get results because starting new cursors is expensive for low limits. I tried doing 62k rows with 1k and even 10k limit just now and it is very slow and unusable since I have to start more than 6 cursors. I'll just stick with not supporting 2.3.3.... It is the latest build that I get CursorWindow ERROR instead of WARN.

Here is what I did though. This is probably the best algorithm I think. Don't have to do queries twice etc. However, it can get pretty slow with big queries and small limits so you have to test out what works best a lot. In my case, it's not fast enough for my purposes since it doesn't handle 62k rows well.

```
int cursorCount = 0;
int limit = 1000; //whatever you want
while (true)
{
    Cursor cursor = builder.query(mDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase(), columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null, Integer.toString(limit));
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    } else if (!cursor.moveToFirst()) { //if it is empty, return null
        return null;
    }
    cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
    if (cursorCount % limit != 0)
    {
        return cursor;
    }
    limit+=1000; //same amount as the one above
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When cursor.getCount(); is an empty cursor, it will return 0 and the modulus operation `cursorCount % limit` will throw a `java.lang.ArithmeticException: divide by zero` error. Here are the updated codes:

```
    int cursorCount = 0;
    int limit = 1000; //whatever you want

    while (true) {

        //add codes for executing database query

        cursorCount = cursor.getCount();
        if (cursorCount > 0 && cursorCount % limit != 0) {
            return cursor;
        }
        limit += 1000; //same amount as the one above

        if (cursorCount == 0) {
            cursor.close(); // close the cursor if it's empty
            return null; // return null to indicate no suggestion found
        }
    }
```