# Android SQLite permanent data

Tags: android, database, sqlite, permanent

I'm developing simple application for collecting expenses. For now I keep data using SQLiteDatabase. I have 2 questions:

1) When I clear application data in Settings->Application then SQLite db is lost. Is there any way to keep data permanently on device even if application will be deleted ?

2) How about SQLite db capacity ? In case of my app, it should keep data from several months or years. Does sqlite db on android have any size restrictions ?

Comment: Regarding question one, one idea is to move your database to external storage.

Comment: for the backup of data see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html

Comment: Depending on the amount of information and desired visual style, you could create a CSV (comma-separated values) file that is saved on the SD card.  This could then be viewed on the device, or imported into a spreadsheet program.

Answer (score 0):

1) No, and you don't want that. When the user deletes the application, he doesn't want any data left on his device. That would be bad practice, and people would give you bad reviews for that.

2) I don't think there's any limit, it will depend on the physical storage available. Check [that for more metrics](http://www.sqlite.org/limits.html) around SQLite.

Also, [this has some useful information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407442/android-sqlite-and-huge-data-sets).

Comment: Is it possible to install normal SQL (not Lite) database on device with android ?