# Android Cursor maximum size

Tags: android, database, sqlite, limit, android-cursor

It appears that Cursors in android can only hold up to 1 MB of data.

What would be the most efficient way to pull the maximum number of rows from a table in a SQLite database that stays under the 1 MB limit?

Comment: The best way I have come up with so far is to sample a few rows and "estimate" how many rows you can pull.  You just have to make sure you never go over the 1MB limit.

Comment: the best method is to use the concept of paging, that means get the data from database in parts ,getting rows ten by ten and clearing the cursor before the next retrieving from database.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a hard and fast way to determine the right limit, but I looked in the CursorWindow documentation and found that `copyStringToBuffer (int row, int column, CharArrayBuffer buffer)` seems promising as CharArrayBuffer has a integer field called sizeCopied and the method `copyStringToBuffer` takes the text at the specified row and column. Maybe you can get the size from the buffer and add for each row and column you have? If you're using SQLiteCursor, you can use `setWindow(CursorWindow window)` to set your own window.

Answer (score -1):

You can put LIMIT clause, so that rows are fetched in parts.

Comment: Right but how would I determine what the appropriate limit is?

Comment: Then you can divide equally or whatever way you like

Comment: I don't think you understand.  I'm trying to find the best way to determine how many rows in an arbitrary table is equal to 1MB.  In one table it may be 1000 rows and in another table it may be 500 rows.

Comment: Yes but not the size of the rows

Comment: This is the way you can acheive this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9873869/android-how-to-query-huge-database-in-android-cursor-size-is-limited-to-1mb

Comment: The answers on that last question state that you shouldn't do it.  For 99% of applications I would agree, but I have a special need for a non market application where I need to achieve this.