# Sqlite database to change TextView in android app

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, mobile-application

I am setting my textview using columns from a sqlite database file.Problem is that when i change the view back and forth, there is a very obvious lag while it retrieves from the database.Here is the code:

```
public class Flipcard extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    LinearLayout layMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.FlashCardFront);
    layMain.setOnClickListener(this);
    Cursor cur;
    DbH db = null;
    TextView tv=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_Word);
    TextView txtView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.TV_CardNo);
    try {
        db=new DbH(this);
    } catch (IOException e2) {

        e2.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        db.createdatabase();
    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    db.opendatabase();
    cur=db.data();
    cur.moveToFirst();
    tv.setText(cur.getString(0));
    cur.close();
}
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i=new Intent(this,Flipcard_back.class);
startActivity(i);
}

}
```

the other java file that is being called on click is:

```
 public class Flipcard_back extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main_back);
    LinearLayout layMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.FlashCardRear);
    layMain.setOnClickListener(this);
}
public void onClick(View v) {
Intent i=new Intent(this,Flipcard.class);
startActivity(i);
}
}
```

which is actually calling previous one.The problem is i'm one a very initial phase on my app development.Right now i am only trying to change two textviews in first java file using my database.When i switch back and forth there is a lag of around a second.How do i correct it? am i doing something wrong.
      Also i am not able to retrieve all the rows using getstring(1) etc.Why so?How do i get the columns one by one?

Comment: Edit: Logcat shows following every time i switch back and forth:           need to grow: mSize=1048576, size=70, freeSpace()=26, numRows=2736      not growing since there are already 2736 row(s), max size=1048576          failed allocating fieldDir at startPos 0row 2736. what does this mean?

Comment: Please follow this example of a [detailed logcat.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10263248/android-unable-to-instantiate-activity-classnotfound-fails-on-one-eclipse)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lag is caused by accessing your database in your main thread, you want to have it run in its own thread.  Here is a the Developer's Guide on [Processes and Thread](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/processes-and-threads.html#Threads) which will give you the grand overview.  Look into something like AsyncTask next, for one approach to accessing databases.

As for not getting results from your database, I cannot tell without seeing the class associated with `db`. Include that code and any logcat errors in your question if you want more help.

**EDIT**

With the error code you provided I found this link to a [similar question and detailed answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1407442/android-sqlite-and-huge-data-sets)

Answer (score 0):

My experience from sqlite + android is that its initially very slow when quering the database, but after that it can retrieve large amounts of data very fast. If you want to avoid lag, use a file instead.
My tiny experience comes from developing the dictionary app Wordlist Pro where I had to abandon the database for textfiles since it was way too slow (and big in size).